# jQuery global events and performance?

Tags: performance, jquery, activity-indicator

I was in search of a way to show a status indicator using jQuery and I found a solution in the jQuery Cookbook, it showed this solution

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#ajaxStatus')
         .ajaxStart(function() {
            $(this).show();
        })
         .ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });

        .....
  })(jQuery);
```

then it cautioned,

> If you experience performance issues in your application, it may be because
>   of the cost of event propagation if there is a significantly large
>   number of elements. In this case, setting global to false may give you
>   a performance improvement.

So first should I use the solution showed above and will it be a performance issue as my site and js code gets larger and larger?

Should I avoid jQuery global events, just turn it off like the paragraph says?

Lastly, how do you guys show a simple indicator while an ajax request is being performed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Honestly, I think this caution is *valid*, but at the same time, outdated.  Look at the jQuery source here:  http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L290

It shows how a global event is *now* handled:

```
if ( jQuery.event.global[ type ] ) {
  jQuery.each( jQuery.cache, function() {
    if ( this.events && this.events[type] ) {
      jQuery.event.trigger( event, data, this.handle.elem );
    }
  });
}
```

It *used* to be:

```
jQuery("*").add([window, document]).trigger(type, data);
```

So it's not triggering on **every** element like it used to, which made the large number of elements warning a very real concern, it instead loops over elements that have registered or the event, and only if *any* have registered, so it's *much* better on performance now.

---

For your questions:

> So first should I use the solution showed above and will it be a performance issue as my site and js code gets larger and larger?

Yes, the solution above is just fine, I've yet to see a page large enough for this to be an issue, after the global events optimization I outlined above.

> Should I avoid jQuery global events, just turn it off like the paragraph says?

Nope, you can pretty much ignore that paragraph is using any jQuery after [this change](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/cf78e396db1b986360c32fb0ca071a0fb90da064) was made.

> Lastly, how do you guys show a simple indicator while an ajax request is being performed?

Exactly as you have in your question :)

Comment: Thank you so much Nick!  Indeed, the book I referenced is written last year.  Great to know things improved since, I'll use the solution then.  Thanks.